# UML association understanding problem

Tags: uml

I've been using UML for a while and I've read few articles, books, forums about it but I still don't REALLY understand when two classes should be connected with association line (a simple line or arrow (or are these not the same?)). I'll provide three examples - can you tell me which one will cause the two classes to be in this relationship?

1.

```
//a field of OtherClass
    public class MainClass
    {
        private OtherClass other;
    }
```

2.

```
//method argument
    public class MainClass
    {
        public void Action(OtherClass other)
        { }
    }
```

3.

```
//method return value
    public class MainClass
    {
        public OtherClass Action()
        { }
    }
```

4.

```
//used inside a method
    public class MainClass
    {
        private Something something;

        public void Action()
        {
            OtherClass other = something.GetOtherClass();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all an arrow represents *navigability* of the association. Single arrow means *unidirectional* relation, in this case only the source class knows about the target class. Arrow on both ends means *bidirectional* relation, where both classes know about each other. If no arrows are present the association can be either bidirectional by default or suppressed for the sake of readability. In practice you should draw arrows only when you want to emphasize the direction of the association.

When it comes to your second question, only the first case describes an (unidirectional) association between `MainClass` and `OtherClass`. Neither arguments nor return values imply association in the UML sense (although both imply dependency). In the last example there is an association between `MainClass` and `Something` class through the `something` attribute. As a rule of thumb you should look for associations in attributes.

Please note that there is a concept of `dependency` in UML and it is represented by a dashed line.

Pozdrowienia!

Comment: That pretty much sums it up. +1

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Rewrote answer following discussion in comments (thanks to [Chimp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18364/chimp) for pointing out what I overlooked in Example 4)

Example 1: OtherClass is an attribute of MainClass, and thus is modelled as an association.

Examples 2 and 3: OtherClass is referenced within the class definition, although not stored within an attribute, hence is a dependency.

Example 4: The Something class is an attribute, and therefore an association, while the referenced OtherClass, which is not stored in an attribute, and so it is dependency.

Within UML, dependencies and associations are both types of Relationship and are not strictly related (except through a common supertype), although in my opinion an association implies a dependency.

Associations are indicated by a line between the 2 classes with multiplicities at each end. Navigability is indicated by arrows showing which class is aware of which (E.g. Class A ___> Class B means A is aware of B, but not the other way around) navigability in both directions is shown by arrows at both ends. Where there is no arrows it usually safer to make no assumptions about navigability unless stated elsewhere.

Dependencies are indicated by a dashed line with an arrow from the dependant class (client) to the class being depended on (supplier) (E.g. A ----> B means A is dependant on B). Dependencies show that a class is referenced at some point, and as such the client is dependent on operations provided by the supplier, but it doesn't indicate how it is referenced (unlike an association that suggests a reference stored in an attribute).

Comment: ok but isn't the class aware of the classes provided as arguments? and are you sure about what you're saying, because i'm looking for an answer "this is what the theory says, end of topic"?

Comment: hmm, I could probably rephrase that a bit: the journey from mind to keyboard isn't always an easy one, and I think I've lost some meaning on the way.

Associations are expressed as attributes. It is acceptable to display associations in UML in the same manner as primitive data types, but using the connecting lines is usually more informative.


I'm afraid I can't think of an explanation to show why arguments to methods don't constitute an association (other than "because they don't" which isn't an explanation at all).

But, regardless, I am sure this is correct.

Comment: By the way, I always keep a copy of UML Distilled to hand when working with UML, I find it a very good reference: http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#uml

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote this answer. Only example 1 is an association; 2,3 and 4 are dependencies.

Comment: Although I agree that 2 and 3 are simple dependencies, I think that by modelling 4 as dependency you lose the meaning that the class in question is also an attribute, so would prefer an association (which I believe implies dependency) as it makes it clearer that the class is not only referenced, but also stored as data within the class in question.

That said, I'm interested to hear other people's thoughts on this (as there's rarely a single way of doing it) and will pose a question about whether associations imply dependencies.

Comment: For Reference, the question that I have asked can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152335/

Comment: Just to make it clear: in example 4, the relationship from MainClass to OtherClass is a dependency; the relationship from MainClass to Something is an association.

Comment: ah, I misread the code... mistake on my part, didn't pick up on the reference to OtherClass... now I realise, I do actually agree with you and will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

An association represents two or more related properties.

In example 1, MainClass has a property of type OtherClass. If OtherClass has an explicit property of type MainClass then there will be a bidirectional association between the class; if OtherClass has an implicit property of type MainClass (i.e. there is no attribute, but the relationship can be derived by working in the other direction) then there will be a unidirectional association from MainClass to OtherClass.

In examples 2, 3 and 4, MainClass does not have any properties of type OtherClass. It is dependent on the OtherClass though, so there would be a dependency relationship from MainClass to OtherClass. In code this is represented by a **using** or **#include**.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use two different connectors in UML:

1. When a class is dependent on the implementation of another. This would imply that a class is creating or handling an instance of another. So the calling class is dependent on the implementation class. This would be evident in all of your examples.
2. When a class extends or implements another.

Comment: So, which connectors do you use in each case?