# Does an association imply a dependency in UML?

Tags: dependencies, associations, uml

In discussion about my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142339/uml-association-understanding-problem/1142436#1142436) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142339/uml-association-understanding-problem/1142436), there was some disagreement over how to model this code:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private Something something;

    public void Action()
    {
        OtherClass other = something.GetOtherClass();
    }
}
```

The key points being:

1. the `Something` class is an attribute in `MainClass`, suggesting an association
2. the `Something` class is referenced within `MainClass`, suggesting a dependency

   A dependency is supposed to be a specialised association

However, since a dependency is can be appropriate in cases where the supplier class is not an attribute, does using a dependency "hide" the intention that the `Something` is an attribute, rather than simply referenced?

Furthermore, does an association, which represents an attribute in a class, imply a dependency because it is being stored (and presumably referenced and used in some way).

**So**, with reference to the above points, does an association imply a dependency, and how would you model the above code in a class diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependencies and associations are two different concepts. According to the UML metamodel, both are two independent subclasses of the "Relationship" metaclass.

However, it is true, that in your scenario I'd just model an association between the two classes and not a dependency. The fact that the two classes are connected through an association already make them dependent.

Comment: +1 for pointing out I misunderstood the relationship between associations and dependencies. Confirmed it by digging through the UML Superstructure specification from http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.2/

Comment: Left open to see if there were any more answers, since there haven't been any and I'm satisfied this answer addresses the question, I've accepted it

Answer (score 0):

I would argue it really depends what you are trying show with the particular diagram.  You could model it with either.  You could even use composition if it made sense in the context.

Answer (score 0):

There are three class, the first is  `MainClass`, the second is `Something`, and the third is  `OtherClass`. It is so simple if you use UML tools to generate the class you will see the diagrams. It is compose of thee class. I believe the dash line connected between `MainClass` and `OtherClass`. The line(association) connected between `MainClass` and `Something`.